# Flower dashboard doesn't show up

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, celery, flower

We are using Django for our Python website. We are using `celery==4.1.1` to run background tasks. Everything works fines. But, I cannot monitor the tasks processed or processing like we use to have in older celery with `djcelery`. I heard of `flower`.

I used

```
flower==0.9.2
tornado==4.5.2
babel==2.5.3
```

Here is the command in Supervisor:

```
[program:celery-flower]
command=flower -A lbb --natural-time --url_prefix=flower  --port=5555 --inspect --enable-events
```

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
upstream application {
    server lbb-app:8000;
}

upstream application2 {
    server lbb-app:5555;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 4G;   # adjust to taste
    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

    location /work {
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  application;
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.

    location / {
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  application;
    }
    location /flower/ {
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass application2;
    }
}
```

I cannot open the dashboard. It shows 504 error.

Here are the logs from celery-flower-stderr.

```
[I 180605 08:25:06 command:106] Visit me at http://localhost:5555
[I 180605 08:25:06 command:107] Broker: amqp://guest:**@ec2-xx-2xx-1xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5672//
[W 180605 08:25:06 state:74] Broker info is not available if --broker_api option is not configured. Also make sure RabbitMQ Management Plugin is enabled (rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management)
[I 180605 08:25:06 mixins:224] Connected to amqp://guest:**@ec2-xx-2xx-1xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5672//
```

Is `--broker-api` compulsory to just show up flower dashboard? Is there any problem in my settings? What should I do?  I suspect this has to do with my nginx conf. Please point out anything wrong in it.

## Edited

I added the `broker-api=http://guest:**@ec2-xx-2xx-1xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:15672/api/` and rabbitmq management command.

Now the message in celery-flower-stderr:

```
[I 180606 03:56:15 command:139] Visit me at http://localhost:5555
[I 180606 03:56:15 command:144] Broker: amqp://guest:**@ec2-xx-2xx-1xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5672//
[I 180606 03:56:15 command:147] Registered tasks: 
    ['(redacted)',
     'celery.accumulate',
     'celery.backend_cleanup',
     'celery.chain',
     'celery.chord',
     'celery.chord_unlock',
     'celery.chunks',
     'celery.group',
     'celery.map',
     'celery.starmap',
     'celery_haystack.tasks.CeleryHaystackSignalHandler',
     'celery_haystack.tasks.CeleryHaystackUpdateIndex',]
[I 180606 03:56:15 mixins:224] Connected to amqp://guest:**@ec2-xx-2xx-1xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5672//
[W 180606 03:56:17 control:44] 'stats' inspect method failed
[W 180606 03:56:17 control:44] 'active_queues' inspect method failed
[W 180606 03:56:17 control:44] 'registered' inspect method failed
[W 180606 03:56:17 control:44] 'scheduled' inspect method failed
[W 180606 03:56:17 control:44] 'active' inspect method failed
[W 180606 03:56:17 control:44] 'reserved' inspect method failed
[W 180606 03:56:17 control:44] 'revoked' inspect method failed
[W 180606 03:56:17 control:44] 'conf' inspect method failed
```

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't show up"?

Comment: When I type https://website.com/flower/ , it shows 504 error after a while. I cannot see flower dashboard itself.

Comment: What happens if you `curl http://localhost:5555/` from the server Flower is running on? That way you can rule out Nginx problems.

Comment: I am getting html of flower dashboard(probably).

Comment: try `proxy_pass` directive instead. imo the problem is with nginx conf.